# Adding Background Image to Login Page with Overlay

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I am having trouble adding a background image to my login page: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YnhH.png) that contains an overlay.

I tried to play around with CSS and HTML code in my program and looking for the answer online but I still was not able to get a background image to show up. The image that I want to use as a background is called "books.jpg".

Layout of my application: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHSS2.png)

LoginView class:

```
package com.example.application.views;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.Composite;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.applayout.DrawerToggle;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.dependency.CssImport;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Div;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.H1;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.html.Image;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.login.LoginForm;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.login.LoginOverlay;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.tabs.Tabs;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.BeforeEnterEvent;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.BeforeEnterObserver;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.PageTitle;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;

@Route("login")
@PageTitle("Login | Sample App")
public class LoginView extends Div implements BeforeEnterObserver {

   private final LoginOverlay login = new LoginOverlay();

   public LoginView(){

      addClassName("login-view");
      LoginOverlay loginOverlay = new LoginOverlay();
      loginOverlay.setTitle("Sample App");
      loginOverlay.setOpened(true);
      loginOverlay.setAction("login");
      add(loginOverlay);

   }

   @Override
   public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent beforeEnterEvent) {
      // inform the user about an authentication error
      if(beforeEnterEvent.getLocation()
            .getQueryParameters()
            .getParameters()
            .containsKey("error")) {
         login.setError(true);
      }
   }
}
```

Index.html class:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!---->

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <style>
    body, #outlet {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }

    [part="backdrop"] {
         background-image: url(../images/books.png);
         background-size: cover;
     }
  </style>
  <!-- index.ts is included here automatically (either by the dev server or during the build) -->
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Styles.css class

```
@import url('./views/list-view.css');
@import url('lumo-css-framework/all-classes.css');

a[highlight] {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;

}
 .login-view {
   background-image: url("images/books.jpg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is almost exactly the same as your other one about login views, the solution is also almost exactly the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75028635/396573

Place the image in the `frontend` folder, and then target the correct component part with this CSS:

```css
.login-view vaadin-login-overlay-wrapper::part(backdrop) {
  background: url("images/prepbooks.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Did not work sorry

Comment: Did you put the image in the theme folder like mentioned in the other answer? And did you put the CSS in the theme styles.css file, like in the other answer?

Comment: yes I did. Layout of my application: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHSS2.png

Comment: Styles.css: https://imgur.com/a/B9SWMZ5

Comment: Thanks. I had the selector wrong. I checked it now, and instead of `vaadin-login-overlay` you need to use `vaadin-login-overlay-wrapper`. I updated the answer.